# SonarQube plugin: how to get property value from command line -D

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-api, sonarqube-plugin

I am new to sonar plugin development. I wrote a plugin and add PropertyDefine to context. And then I wanna get my property value passed by

> gradle sonarqube -Dmy.proper.name=xxx

I don't know what are the next steps? Plz help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @agabrys thanks for your answer. But I found out that if you wanna get the property from **Scanner side**, you need make a `PostJob` like class to deal with it. I didn't clearly know that so I didn't know why I couldn't get that property. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

All `-D` parameters can be get by using [java.lang.System](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) class:

```
String valueOrNull = System.getProperty("my.proper.name");
```

or

```
String valueOrDefault = System.getProperty("my.proper.name", "defaultValue");
```